# N-step ahead residuals from an Arima model in R

Tags: r

I have an armax (5,0,4) model with exogenous data, where I find the parameters in R with:

```
model <- arima(measurements, order=c(5,0,4), include.mean=FALSE, xreg=exDat)
```

As I understand it, `residuals(model)` gives me the one-step ahead residuals, where the original data is compared with the model result. Is there an automated way to get n-step ahead residuals?

If not, how can predict be used give forecasts throughout the "measurements" data (backtesting)? Using:

```
forecasted_data <- predict(model, n.ahead=12, interval='prediction', newxreg = new_exDat)
```

Will only give a forecast beyond the horizon of the measurements data. The dataset is so large, that creating new models can take several hours, so I only want to build the model once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find multi-step ahead residuals without recreating the model, you have to do:

```
period_to_analyse <- length(measurements)

for (i in 1:period_to_analyse){
fit <- Arima(measurements[1:i], model = model, xreg=exDat[1:n,]
fcast <- forecast(fit, h=forecast_horizon, xreg = exDat[(n+i):(n+i+forecast_horizon-1)])
residuals[i,] <- fcast - measurements[1:i]
}
```

NB. Arima, arima, and auto.arima appear to be different processes. The only function that works with the above is Arima with an uppercase A.